# exclude uncultured and environmental samples from NT databases

Tags: blastn, nt

I'm using blast locally against NT databases and I'm excluding the uncultured and environmental samples by the taxonomy ID. Is there another way to exclude them entirely, without using the taxonomy ID?

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7384/taxon-exclude-list-for-searching-local-blast-database-using-blastn

Comment: If trying to gain database quality by excluding uncultured and environmental, RefSeq may be helpful.  Database can be downloaded locally. ```update_blastdb.pl --showall``` shows pre-formatted databases (refseq_genomic).  See link, "Reference Sequence (RefSeq)" at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/all/ for more detail.